# Converting CSR to Certificate in Java

Tags: java, certificate, inputstream, csr

I'm building a Java SCEP server. This means that when device connects to my server, it writes a certificate signing request to the device's InputStream. I want to be able to read this request and create a signed certificate which I can then write back to the device. Is there a good way to do this in Java (I'm aware of coomand-line tools like openssl and keytool that do this but it's not what I want).

Comment: You normally writes into an OutputStream, not InputStream

Comment: Something wrong here. The device owns its own keypair, and its CSR essentially wraps its public key. Unless you have the private key, which destroys the entire point of it, you can't generate a self-signed certificate. You can generate a certificate signed by some one else, i.e. you, but not by the device.

Comment: @gerrytan Yes sorry I meant OutputStream.

Comment: @EJP What I meant to say is the device requests the certificate and I, the server, wants to create the certificate. It's not self-signed.

Comment: The idea of these comments is to get you to *fix your question,* so it has some permanent value.